# Obtaining $\nu \log (1+\frac{\theta}{\alpha}) $ as limit of $(\delta \gamma)- \delta (\gamma^{1/\kappa} + 2 \theta)^\kappa$

Tags: limits

Can I obtain the expression
$$
\nu \log (1+\frac{\theta}{\alpha})
$$
as a limit from the expression
$$
\delta \gamma- \delta  (\gamma^{1/\kappa} + 2 \theta)^\kappa
$$
with $\kappa \to 0$ where $\nu$ and $\alpha$ can be chosen dependent of $\delta, \gamma, \kappa$ but not $\theta$.

The motivation is [this document](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~shephard/introlevy120608.pdf) where it is claimed that the $\Gamma$ distribution arises as a limit of the tempered stable distribution, the first is the cumulant transform of the $\Gamma$ distribution and the second of the tempered stable.

I'm guessing to somehow use the limit
$$
\lim_{w\to \infty} w (z^{1/w}-1) = \log (z)
$$ 
but I haven't made any mentionable progress.